# Modern MMC like Web GUI for server management?

Tags: user-interface, mmc

we are thinking to make a management tool for the win app. I was thinking about MMC but it needs to be web based one. Please can you advice me what to use to build nice mmc like web based management app. Maybe something like OWA 2010 or MS's managed services.

Thanks